# Not getting c# webmethod json sting on another page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, json

I have created a `WebMethod` (dt) in code behind page `c#`  of **default.aspx** page, i want to display response data(json string) on another page like **default2.aspx** page and bind `json` response data using `ng-repeat`  `angularjs`

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getJson()
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    data = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["getData"];
    return data;
}
```

`WebMethod` defined in **default.aspx.cs**,

I want to bind json data*(getting from webmethod)* using `ng-repeat` `angularjs` in **default2.aspx** page from button click on **default.aspx** page. I am getting json string on same page, but don't know that how to show this on another page.

Any suggestion or help....

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like the follwing on your second page i.e `Default2.aspx`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/getJson',
    .
    .
});
```

Comment: It should work is any error you are getting at the time of call.

Comment: Just put the console.log in your success and error method like below            success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }